# Why navigation bar text size is not affected by accessibility settings in iOS 7/8?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, accessibility

I am using dynamic fonts in my iOS app to make it accessible to people with poor eyesight. All text in my app obeys font size settings in General > Accessibility > Larger Text.

For some reason the text size in Navigation Bar remains the same regardless of the font size settings. When I use dynamic fonts in storyboard for navigation bar it does not seem to apply them.

Even Apple apps like Settings, Notes, Music ignore accessibility settings in Navigation Bar.

Why does Navigation Bar ignore font size in accessibility settings? Is it a bug in iOS? If so, should I bother and manually implement accessibility-friendly Navigation Bar or wait until Apple fixes it in the next update?

Tested both in iOS 7 and 8.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Cramming all of that large font text into the navigation bar just wouldn't work. So instead, they decided to keep the size the same and, if you're using the accessibility font sizes (largest 5), holding your finger on a tab or navigation bar element will display a HUD-style message with the word in larger type. Works for icons too.